# Insert Image Dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am using a program (jAlbum) to create a gallery and in that gallery it has a place for more information about the photo. Currently it just displays `Photo Info ^`. I have an image I would like to insert into the span that contains the words Photo Info. I would do this in the program but after searching I cannot find that span (I believe it might be generated with javascript but I cannot find the line that generates it). So I figured I can insert this image dynamically using jQuery. I am not sure how to do this as javascript is not my strong suit. Here is how the HTML for the span looks currently:

```
<span id="lightwindow_info_tab_span" class="up"> Photo Info</span>
```

Here is how it should look after the image is inserted into the code:

```
<span id="lightwindow_info_tab_span" class="up"><img class="inline" 
  src="/Images/Icons/info.png" />Photo Info</span>
```

What is the best way to do this? Remember I am not super strong at javascript (just strong enough to break stuff => ) so please provide an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#lightwindow_info_tab_span')
              .prepend('<img class="inline" src="/Images/Icons/info.png" />');
```

Here I use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend), because according to OP's post, the image is before the Text.

You can also use [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto)

```
$('<img class="inline" src="/Images/Icons/info.png" />')
              .prependTo('#lightwindow_info_tab_span');
```

or

```
var yourImg = $('<img/>', {
                           "class" :"inline", // or className: "inline"
                            src:"/Images/Icons/info.png"
                         });

$("#lightwindow_info_tab_span").prepend(yourImg);
```

You could also use:

```
$('#lightwindow_info_tab_span').html(function(index, oldHTML) {
    return '<img class="inline" src="/Images/Icons/info.png" />' + oldHTML;
});
```

**But I would go for options before this**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried the first code listed and it doesn't work. I do not get any errors on the page just no icon.

Comment: @Lynda your image inserting code is outside of `$j(document).ready()` function. put the above code within that function and I think it will works just fine

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did not work, I believe it is conflicting with some other scripts. I have had this issue before, no errors are thrown but it just doesn't work. With that said trying to work out this issue I came across the code in the program that I can edit to insert my icon. So now I do not need the jQuery solution. Thank You for your help and assistance with my issue. =>

Answer (score 2):

```
var img = $('<img class="inline" src="/Images/Icons/info.png" />');
$("#lightwindow_info_tab_span").prepend(img);
```

or

```
var img = $('<img/>', {"class" :"inline", src:"/Images/Icons/info.png"});
$("#lightwindow_info_tab_span").prepend(img);
```

Comment: @adeneo `class` can't be used, you should use `"class"` or `className`

Comment: @thecodeparadox - I'll add some quotes just for you, for me it works fine without them!

Comment: @adeneo yup mate, you add the `""` later, but that don't when I wrote the comment

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<img class="inline" src="/Images/Icons/info.png" />').prependTo("#lightwindow_info_tab_span")
```