# Dynamically load an image inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Below is my code. I am attempting to load a picture in a modal. The picture exists on the page and I am able to get the source. Is there a way to simply load the image into a modal on click as I am trying to do here? I am able to click on an image and ALERT out the source; but when I try to plug the source into the function; nothing happens.

I am using ZEND but I do not believe that is relevant to the situation at hand and so I did not tag the question with the ZEND tag.

**Can anyone explain what I need to do in order to load my image in a MODAL on click?**

```
<?php
    $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/default/index/designbox.css'));
    $this->jQuery()->onLoadCapturestart();
?>
<!-- Modal Done Here -->
$('.boxDES').click(function() {
    pic1 = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('src');
    alert(pic1);

    $(pic1).dialog(
        {
            modal:      true,
            draggable:  false,
            title:      'Designs',
            height:     'auto',
            width:      'auto',
            open:       function(){
                            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                                jQuery(pic).dialog('close');
                            })
                        }
        }
    );
});
<?php $this->jQuery()->onLoadCaptureEnd(); ?>
<div id="designGroup">

    <div id="title">
        <?php echo strtoupper($this->object->GetType()); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="boxText">
        <?php echo $this->object->GetDescription(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $links = $this->object->GetLinks(); ?>
    <div id="pictureBox">
        <ul id="grid">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img id="<?php echo $links[0];?>" class="boxDES" src="<?php echo '/images/design/thumbs/' . $links[0]; ?>"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img id="<?php echo $links[1];?>" class="boxDES" src="<?php echo '/images/design/thumbs/' . $links[1]; ?>"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img id="<?php echo $links[2];?>" class="boxDES" src="<?php echo '/images/design/thumbs/' . $links[2]; ?>"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img id="<?php echo $links[3];?>" class="boxDES" src="<?php echo '/images/design/thumbs/' . $links[3]; ?>"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 This is how to build a variable that holds my IMG.

var catIMG = $('<img/>', {
                                "class" :"inline",
                                src:pic1
                        });
```

The below is the now fixed and complete JSCRIPT -

```
$('.boxDES').click(function() {
    pic1 = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('src');
    var catIMG = $('<img/>', {
                        "class" :"inline",
                        src:pic1
                });

    $(catIMG).dialog(
        {
            modal:      true,
            draggable:  false,
            title:      'Designs',
            height:     'auto',
            width:      'auto',
            open:       function(){
                            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                                jQuery(pic).dialog('close');
                            })
                        }
        }
    );
});
```

I was able to find this information here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788966/1583066